# Javascript css selector for nested classes

Tags: javascript, css, class, nested, pseudocode

I am creating a CSS selector for homework. I have managed to extract and get single selectors - e.g. `#_id`, but I cannot work out how to get a result for nested ones such as : `div#_id._class` [NOTE: I cannot use any libraries to do this or `querySelectorAll`]

The pseudo-code below is an example of what I currently have:

```
if (regex match for class) {
    for (a in match for class) {
        if (a.indexOf('.') > -1) {
            var split_ = a.split(".");
            var dot = split_[0];
            var class_ = split_[1];
            array_of_elements = document.getElementsByClassName(class_);
        }
    }
```

The problem is when the selector is nested I can't extract the whole thing using a similar method. E.g. look for an id, look for a class. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
else if (is id) {
    split by ("#");
    for (each result) {
        if (has class ('.')) {
            array_elements = document.getElementById(result_ID)
                             .getElementsByClassName(result_CLASS_NAME));
        } else {
            array_elements = (document.getElementsByTagName(result));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be pseudo code?  Because `if(regex match for class){` doesn't make any sense to me as javascript.

Comment: Yes sorry pseudo code

Comment: So what can you use? And which CSS selector patterns are you trying to implement? There are [many](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)...

Comment: And I think you actually mean a *[sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sequence)*, rather than *nested classes*. Phrasing is important here :)

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned is actually called a *sequence of simple selectors*.

```
div#_id._class
```

It consitst of three *simple selectors* `div`, `#_id`, `._class`

What you need to do is get elements by tag name, and then check for matches on all of the remaining simple selectors. I'll give you an idea here:

```
function qSelector(sequence) {
    var tagName = getTag(sequence) || '*'; // 'div'
    var ids = getIDs(sequence); // ['_id']
    var classes = getClasses(sequence); // ['_class']
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    return [].filter.call(els, function (el) {
        for (id in ids) { if (el.id != id) return false; }
        for (cls in classes) { if (el.className not contains cls) return false; }
        return true;
    });
}
```

This is more versatile than your approach and can be easily generalized to work with selectors containing spaces.

I'll leave the implementation of the `get…` helpers to you.